# Hue gradient as colorbar on y axis with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, colorbar

I have the following Hue/Saturation 2D-Histogram. There are two things i like to change but don't know how.
[image: Hue/saturation 2D Histogram]

**1)** Is it possible to replace the y-axis values (0-20) with a colorbar that shows a hue-gradient?The following code builds a numpy array of the gradient.

```
hue_gradient = np.linspace(0, 1)
hsv = np.ones(shape=(1, len(hue_gradient), 3), dtype=float)
hsv[:, :, 0] = hue_gradient
all_hues = hsv_to_rgb(hsv)
```

So the question is how to set this array as a colorbar and locate it next to the left side of the image.

**2)** I want to scale the colorbar to the right of the image, so that it does not exceed it on top and bottom?

I hope somebody can help me.

EDIT:
To clarify what I want to see at the y-axis (Hue) instead of the values 0 to 20.
I have following gradient. I generate it with the code above. And I want this gradient visualized as a colorbar instead of the values 0 to 20 of the Hue axis.
Basically: How can i set `all_hues` (Gradient posted below) as data for a colorbar and show it and move the colorbar to the location of the Hue axis ticks.

[image: Hue Gradient]

Current code:

```
fig_synth = plt.figure("synth")
plt.imshow(synth_avrgHistogram, interpolation='nearest', vmin=0, vmax=vmax)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("Saturation")
plt.ylabel("Hue")
```

Comment: can you show us a picture of the desired result for the y-axis? it's not really clear to me...

Comment: Can you please provide a sample data? I would suggest you plot the `y-axis` in log scale, then you would see the variation clearly.

Comment: @Silmathoron I have edited the description. Hope it clarifies my problem.

Comment: @MaThMaX I dont think the y-axis in log scale solves my problem as i dont wont to rescale anything, but replace the scale by a colorbar.

Comment: Ok, now I think I get it. As mentionned in MaThMaX's comment, can you give a minimal working example to make it easier for us?

Comment: I am sorry it is a bigger project so I can just give you a bit of the relevant code.

Comment: I think your logic is not right. As long as you "replace the scale by colorbar", you are actually re-scaling your data. And the plot is just for vitalization only and you can choose whichever way that is proper for user to understand. And by re-scaling, it actually retains your original data but focus more on the changes. Remember, when matplotlib plots, it only takes your data as input and generate the colormap accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I don't know how to do this exactly... the closest thing I can think of is to use `AxesGrid` from these matplotlib examples: [cmap](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) and [edge cbar](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_edge_colorbar.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid
import numpy as np

def demo_right_cbar(fig):
    """
    A grid of 2x1 images. Left will be the colorbar, right the image.
    """
    grid = AxesGrid(fig, 121,  # similar to subplot(122)
                    nrows_ncols=(1,2),
                    axes_pad=0.05,
                    cbar_location="right",
                    cbar_mode="edge",
                    cbar_size="7%",
                    cbar_pad="2%",
                    )
    extent = (0,200,0,200)
    Z = np.random.randint(0,200,(extent[1],extent[3]))
    gradient = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
    gradient = np.vstack((gradient, gradient)).T
    grid[0].imshow(gradient, aspect=100./7., extent=extent)
    grid[1].set_ylabel("Hue")
    grid[0].set_xticks([])
    grid[0].set_ylabel("Hue")

    im = grid[1].imshow(Z, extent=extent, interpolation="nearest", cmap=plt.get_cmap("summer"))
    grid[1].set_xlabel("Saturation")
    print(dir(grid[0]))
    cax = grid.cbar_axes[0]
    cax.colorbar(im)
    cax.toggle_label(True)
    cax.axis[cax.orientation].set_label('Foo')

fig = plt.figure()
demo_right_cbar(fig)

plt.show()
```

This is the best I can do... you'll have to find a way to plot the colors you want in the left "colorbar".

Comment: Thanks @Silmathoron. That was what I was looking for. It seems to be more of a hack but fits my problem perfectly!